# Why is text box value not inserting into database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert document number into `adjustments_config` table in the vm server like this:

```
public string conString = "Data Source=vmrserver;Initial Catalog=Commission_web;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();

if(con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    string q = "insert into adjustments_config(document_number)values('" + TextBoxDocNo.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
}
```

Comment: does cmd returns any error ? 
what is value of TextBoxDocNo.Text ?

Comment: You're vulnerably to SQL Injection. *Always* parameterise your SQL.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="LabelDocNo" runat="server" Text="Document Number:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDocNo" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables (tl;dr: use parameterized queries not string concatenation to pass paremeters)

Comment: First: SQL Injection. Second: Explain what is wrong (unspected behavior, errors)

Comment: I'm doing this but still doesnt work:

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                con.Open();
                if(con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    string q = "insert into adjustments_config(document_number)values(@document_number)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@document_number", TextBoxDocNo.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
                }

Comment: doesnt work is **not** a good description of a problem.

Comment: The form works butwhen I enter a number into textbox and hit submit the figure won't be inserted into the table. This code is in the submit button.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and debug your code

Comment: if you replace the textbox value with hardcoded value will it work? did you open db trace?

Comment: How are you checking if data is inserted or not? Are you checking at the right database?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments (it is hard to read), [edit] your question instead. And while you are there, add the other remarks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't possibly tell what you problem is without more information but your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Perhaps the problem with your code is that your document number has an apostrophe in it, causing your vulnerable code to blow up.
Try this to get you started:

```
try
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into adjustments_config(document_number)values(@docNumber)", con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docNumber", TextBoxDocNo.Text);
        var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // ..validate rows affected
        Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
    }
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```